# How to Examine the error using Manipulate [] to x in [-0.4 0.4], and conclude for small x

Tags: manipulate, series-expansion

How to Examine the error using Manipulate [] for Series of Exp[x] to x in [-0.4 0.4], and conclude for small x[image]

Comment: Post code, not an image.

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@Table[Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}] - Exp[x], {n, 1, nmax}], {x, -.4, .4}], {{nmax, 1}, 1, 10, 1}]`

Comment: What is exactly your error? The function itself is working but perhaps you want a different result?